# OPC UA Server error while starting Cimplicity project

Tags: opc-ua, opc

I have a cimplicity project running and I'm trying to connect it to opc ua server running in my local. Connection is working fine. But I get following error in opc ua server while starting the project:

```
simple_opc_client: /home/fxm/Atlas/OPC-UA/sdk_64/include/uabase/uaarraytemplates.h:50: 
T& UaStackTypeArray<T, fctClear>::operator[](OpcUa_UInt32) const 
[with T = _OpcUa_DataValue, OpcUa_Void (* fctClear)(OpcUa_Void*) = ClearDataValue, OpcUa_UInt32 = unsigned int]: 
Assertion `index<m_noOfElements' failed.
[1]+  Killed                  ./bin/opc_ua_server
Aborted
```

Problem is that I get this issue only if I deploy opc server to kubernetes cluster. It works fine when I try to connect to opc in my vscode devcontainer. Any clues on what could be wrong here?
Is there any configuration that is missed?